# How do I grant access to a clustered file server's admin share?

Tags: windows, powershell, smb, fileserver, failovercluster

I've set up a clustered file server and would like to grant access to the clustered file server's admin share. From my understanding, admin share permissions can't be modified. Is there any way to grant access to a cluster admin share without adding the user/group to BUILTIN\Administrators. Methods to modify the SMB share fail with "The request is not supported" when applied to an admin share.

```
Name ScopeName       AccountName              AccessControlType AccessRight
---- ---------       -----------              ----------------- -----------
D$   *               BUILTIN\Administrators   Allow             Full
D$   *               BUILTIN\Backup Operators Allow             Full
D$   *               NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE Allow             Full
D$   FileServer      BUILTIN\Administrators   Allow             Full       <---
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just define a new share for ``d:\`` that you *are* free to change permissions on? The only thing special about the admin share is that it gets created automatically. (Well, that and that it's intended for use by administrators, obviously.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the suggestion. I want to expose D$ because from my understanding there are Windows applications that depend on the presence of admin shares.

Comment: Those Windows applications would not depend on the share being accessible by non-administrators, and nothing prevents you from having more than one share to the same drive. I'm not aware of any Windows application that would depend on an admin share to a drive, unless it actually had to do something only administrators are supposed to be able to do anyway (notably, just giving an account access to the share will not also give them access to any files, unless those permissions are taken care of separately).